# Using $(this).find with .click() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, find, this

On the click of the plus icon I want the check icon to appear for only the one plus icon in that particular div. Not all plus icons throughout the page. Here is the html followed by the jQuery.

```
<div class="pin">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/nike.jpg" />
        <div class= "hover-popup">
            <h1 class="brand-name">Nike</h1>
            <img class="plus-icon" src="img/plus-icon.png" />
            <img class="check-icon" src="img/check-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/calvinklein.jpg" />
        <div class= "hover-popup">
            <h1 class="brand-name">Calvin Klein</h1>
            <img class="plus-icon" src="img/plus-icon.png" />
            <img class="check-icon" src="img/check-icon.png" />
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".plus-icon").click(
    function () { $(this).find('.check-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).find('.plus-icon').hide(); }
);

$(".check-icon").click(function() {
    function () { $(this).find('.plus-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).find('.check-icon').hide(); }
);
```

Comment: Use a direct selection instead of finding the element

Comment: In the element clicked just don't find it, use `this` directly and in the other one, go to the parent and then get the children and then find the element

Comment: BTW I think find should return an array. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

First find the containing div, since its an ancestor of `.check-icon,.plus-icon` use `.closest()`, then you can use `find()`

```
$(this).closest('.hover-popup').find('.check-icon').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector.

```
$(".plus-icon").click(
    function () { $(this).siblings('.check-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).hide(); }
);

$(".check-icon").click(function() {
    function () { $(this).siblings('.plus-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).hide(); }
);
```

Given your example HTML, this would be the preferred solution.

Alternately, use [`.parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), then use `find` to descend from there.

```
$(".plus-icon").click(
    function () { $(this).parent().find('.check-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).parent().find('.plus-icon').hide(); }
);

$(".check-icon").click(function() {
    function () { $(this).parent().find('.plus-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).parent().find('.check-icon').hide(); }
);
```

Finally, if you are not sure where the `.hover-popup` element will be relative to the button, use [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to locate it, then descend from there.

```
$(".plus-icon").click(
    function () { $(this).closest('.hover-popup').find('.check-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).closest('.hover-popup').find('.plus-icon').hide(); }
);

$(".check-icon").click(function() {
    function () { $(this).closest('.hover-popup').find('.plus-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).closest('.hover-popup').find('.check-icon').hide(); }
);
```

Comment: The best choice definitely

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery your code will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('.plus-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.check-icon').show()
    })
    $('.check-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.plus-icon').show()
    })
})
```

Comment: Plus icon click hides itself and you are doing the opposite in both functions in both cases

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".plus-icon").click(
    function () { $(this).next('.check-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).hide(); }
);

$(".check-icon").click(function() {
    function () { $(this).prev('.plus-icon').show(); },
    function () { $(this).hide(); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use .siblings() function.

e.g

```
$('.plus-icon').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.check-icon').show();
});
```